# How to add tagging to a database

Tags: java, database-design, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Say I am working on a free for all blog where writers are allowed to tag their posts (basically twitter et all). How do I do that so that queries are optimized for speed?

I am thinking of having a tag field where the content is a list of tags

for example an entry may be an article about the president and the tags may be:

```
tag={politics, family, social, news, economy}
```

Notice that the tags are not predefined and that a writer adds them at whim/will.

Is my approach as described the best? Or is there a more efficient approach to doing this?

As it may matter, I am using the app-engine datastore and my language is java.

The ultimate objective is to allow users to search by specific tags, say a user wants to search by the tag "marriage".

Answer (score 2):

First off, you probably do not want any field in a database to be a list of anything, as you typically want it to stay in third normal form at worst and having a column be a list of values violates first normal form.

The way that I've done tagging with small-scale projects (haven't tried anything large so I don't know for sure how scalable or not this would be) is to have a lookup table containing the tags, and a linking table containing the key for the thing to be tagged and the key for its tags.

So it would look something like this:

```
Thing                   Thing_Tags             Tags
------                  -----------            ----
ThingID (Guid)          ThingID (Guid)         TagID (Guid)
otherAttributes         TagID (Guid)           Tag (varchar)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That's a good idea. +1. However, it assumes a relational paradigm. the appengine datastore is non-relational and so for example, a list as a field is a recommended construct. Still I will give some more thought to your answer and see where I can take it. Thanks again.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I am unfamiliar with that particular database engine so I just assumed it was relational since that's the dominant paradigm, at least in my experience. Glad I could still be helpful, though.